# Meteor with Blaze: My helper is not working with {{ #each }} loop

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze

I am using Blaze with Meteor.
I have announcements_list.html

```
<template name="AnnouncementsList">
    <div class="announcements">
        <ul class="collection">
            {{ #each announcements }}
                {{ >announcementItem }}
            {{ /each }}
        </ul>
    </div>
</template>
```

And announcements_list.js

```
Template.AnnouncementsList.helpers({
    announcements: function() {
        return Announcements.find({}, {sort: {createdAt: -1}});
    }
});
```

If I remove the {{ each }} loop, i can read {{ >announcementItem }}. So I think the problem is the function in the helper. Help me please =.= ...

Comment: This looks like it should work. Is there a data context being provided to your `AnnouncementsList` template? i.e. is it wrapped in another template that is giving it data?

Comment: Do you see any error messages in your console?

Comment: Yeah @Khang my bad ... I had some errors in my console with materialize. Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

Is there an announcementItem in your Announcements db or are you trying to access data from a template? If the former, your blaze call should be {{announcementItem}}. In an #each, #unless or #with there is no arrow needed.

Answer (score 0):

You are rendering the same template for every item in `announcements`. Where this template get data from? I would make something like this:

```html
<template name="AnnouncementsList">
    <div class="announcements">
        <ul class="collection">
            {{#each item in announcements}}
                {{> announcementItem item}}
            {{/each }}
        </ul>
    </div>
</template>
```

Then full `item` object will be accessible in your `announcementItem` through

- `Template.instance().data` in helpers and events
- `this.data` in `onCreated` and `onRendered`.